# C++/CLI Обёртка над нативным классом

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

Есть некоторый большой класс, реализованный на C++. Мне нужно использовать его в проекте на C#. Чтобы сэкономить время и не переписывать код я выбрал вариант написания обертки над этим классом на C++/CLI и поместил всё это в библиотеку классов. Однако, у меня возникли трудности с 1 методом, который принимает в параметре указатель на функцию обратного вызова.

Ситуация обстоит следующим образом: нативный класс имеет метод, принимающий указатель на функцию, которая вызывается при наступлении определённых событий. Задача состоит в том, чтобы предоставить в классе-обёртке аналогичный метод, но вместо указателя будет передаваться, соответственно, делегат.

Я упростил код для демонстрации проблемы:

```
class CFoo
{
public:

    bool FooMember;

    CFoo()
    {
        FooMember = true;
    }

    void Call(void(*callback)(CFoo))
    {
        CFoo foo = CFoo();
        std::thread thr([=]() { callback(foo); });
        thr.join();
    }
};

ref class FooWrapper
{
public:

    delegate void ManagedCallback(FooWrapper^ foo);

private:

    delegate void UnmanagedCallback(CFoo foo);

    ManagedCallback^ Callback;

    void FooProc(CFoo foo)
    {
        std::cout << "FooProc: " << (foo.FooMember ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
        Callback(gcnew FooWrapper(&foo));
    }

public:

    CFoo* foo;

    FooWrapper()
    {
        foo = new CFoo();
    }

    FooWrapper(CFoo* foo)
    {
        this->foo = foo;
    }

    void Call(ManagedCallback^ callback)
    {
        Callback = callback;

        UnmanagedCallback^ unmanagedCallback = gcnew UnmanagedCallback(this, &FooWrapper::FooProc);
        IntPtr^ methodPtr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(unmanagedCallback);
        foo->Call(static_cast<void(*)(CFoo)>(methodPtr->ToPointer()));
    }
};

ref class Program
{
public:

    FooWrapper^ Foo;

    void Callback(FooWrapper^ foo)
    {
        Foo = foo;
        std::cout << "Callback: " << (foo->foo->FooMember ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        FooWrapper^ w = gcnew FooWrapper();
        w->Call(gcnew FooWrapper::ManagedCallback(this, &Program::Callback));
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Program^ c = gcnew Program();
    c->Start();

    CFoo foo = *c->Foo->foo; // <- AccessViolationException

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод консоли:

> FooProc: true
>
> Callback: true

Как только созданный в методе `CFoo::Call` поток завершает выполнение, член класса `FooWrapper::foo` разрушается. Я пробовал посмотреть вызовы деструкторов `FooWrapper` и `CFoo`, чтобы убедиться, что объект не уничтожается. Так же можно посмотреть на численное значение самого указателя до попытки разыменовывания и убедиться, что указатель валиден.

Исключение:

> System.AccessViolationException: 'Попытка чтения или записи в
> защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память
> повреждена.'

Может быть есть более удачный способ реализации обертки, либо можно как то исправить существующий.

Comment: Функции обратного вызова обычно принимают еще какой-то непрозрачный пользовательский параметр, через который можно передавать контекст.

Comment: Как это поможет разрешить ситуацию?

Comment: Отпадет необходимость что-то мутить с указателями и маршалингом, исчезнет ошибка.

Comment: Можете более подробно пояснить какой параметр нужно добавить в функцию обратного вызова и в какой класс.

Comment: А в общем есть предположения что именно становится причиной ошибки? Куда может пропадать созданный объект из памяти, ведь деструктор не вызывается.

Comment: У меня куча вопросов по этому коду. В методе `Call` зачем-то создаётся новый экземпляр класса `CFoo`. Зачем? Разве не должны мы напрямую использовать члены текущего объекта, в котором уже находимся?

Comment: _я выбрал вариант написания обертки над этим классом на C++/CLI_ - вот это правильно! За это хвалю. C++/CLI как раз и предназначен для написания обёрток. А вот дальше пишется пример _приложения_ на C++/CLI. За это ругаю. Это нужно делать на C#. Отмазки, что это временно, для проверки работоспособности, не принимаются.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov _"В методе Call зачем-то создаётся новый экземпляр класса CFoo"_ - В вопросе я указал, что сильно упростил код чисто для демонстрации проблемы. Именно так всё и должно быть - создаётся новый экземпляр класса, который передаётся в функцию обратного вызова. И происходить этот вызов может неограниченное количество раз при наступлении определённых условий.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov _"А вот дальше пишется пример приложения на C++/CLI. За это ругаю. Это нужно делать на C#. Отмазки, что это временно, для проверки работоспособности, не принимаются."_ - У меня уже реализовано приложение на C# и библиотека на C++/CLI. Пример чисто для демонстрации исключения. Я думаю, что если исправить представленный в вопросе код, то и в моем проекте ошибка тоже пропадет. Задача исправить то что есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сохраняете указатель на объект CFoo созданный на стеке в методе FooProc и пытаетесь к нему обратиться уже после его разрушения.

Менее очевидная ошибка в том что создав управляемый делегат вы получаете неуправляемую ссылку на него без закрепления делегата в памяти

Comment: За что поставили минус? Я указал на две ошибки в коде, то как их исправить это уже дело автора, т.к. пример кода весьма не однозначен. От себя могу предложить создавать объект на куче в методе CFoo::Call и передавать указатель

Comment: _"создавать объект на куче в методе CFoo::Call и передавать указатель"_ - Это верное решение. Но почему же если объект разрушается, не вызывается деструктор? _"Менее очевидная ошибка в том что создав управляемый делегат вы получаете неуправляемую ссылку на него без закрепления делегата в памяти"_ - Каким образом нужно закрепить делегат в памяти?

Comment: @D.Stark Попробуйте залогировать ваши деструкторы и посмотрите на результат. На счёт закрепления управляемого делегата, то оно выполняется так же как и обычное закрепление управляемого объекта,  вот тут дан пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599228/pin-a-delegate-when-using-a-member-function-for-a-c-style-callback